# How can I prove this equation is correct?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

$$ \left(\begin{array}{c}a+b\\ n\end{array}\right) = \sum_{i=0}^n \left(\begin{array}{c}a\\ k\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{c}b\\ n-k\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: This must be a duplicate, but I don't know how to find the link.

Comment: @WhatsUp a good way to start looking is by remembering the name for the identity.  In this case, "Vandermonde's Identity"

Comment: Have you tried a combinatorial argument?

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks, but I don't even remember the name ^_^ However, strangely I can remember how the proof goes... Human brains are quite interesting.

Comment: @JMoravitz  thanks a lot